# What to do with a local repo once the remote been merged

Tags: git, repository, git-merge, git-squash

I've finished working on a branch of code, it's been deployed live and within Gitlab I've merged and squashed the branch into the master.

Is there any particular reason that I might want to keep the local repository?

Comment: If you want to work on it later, maybe? You'll be able to clone it again I guess, but cloning and deleting the whole repo each time seems an unnecessary burden if you're intending to work again soon enough on it.

Comment: @RomainValeri The OP is probably confounding "repository" with "branch."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh, right, it makes much more sense.